# How to fix this Spacement String Method with Break Line and FormatString.Alignment

Tags: c#, winforms, text, graphics

Well, I'm trying to create a method that make a drawString with a custom spacement.
For 1 line this is perfectly ready, but when I have a break line `\n` the next line start in the middle and I don't know why. (This method needs to work in a string with 32+ chars).

And when I put `formatString.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center` and `formatString.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center`the string don't centralize and I don't know why again.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TryApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Form1.
    /// </summary>
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            //
            // Required for Windows Form Designer support
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
            //
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            if( disposing )
            {
                if (components != null) 
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(827, 292);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() 
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            MeasureCharacterRangesRegions(e);
        }

        public void MeasureCharacterRangesRegions(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //
            // Get a more convenient graphics object.
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            // Set up string.
            string measureString            = "This is a test string and \n We have a break line.";
            int    numChars                 = measureString.Length;
            int numCharsLeft = measureString.Length;
            double numRanges                = Math.Ceiling((double) numChars / 32);
            Font stringFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 16.0F);

            List<StringFormat> stringFormats = new List<StringFormat>();
            List<CharacterRange[]> characterRanges = new List<CharacterRange[]>();

            for (int x = 0; x < numRanges; x++) {

                characterRanges.Add(new CharacterRange[numCharsLeft <= 32 ? numCharsLeft : 32]);
                numCharsLeft -= numCharsLeft <= 32 ? numCharsLeft : 32;

                for (int i = 0; i < characterRanges[x].Length; i++)
                    characterRanges[x][i] = new CharacterRange((x * 32) + i, 1);

                StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
                stringFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip;          // Make sure the characters are not clipped
                stringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(characterRanges[x]);
                stringFormats.Add(stringFormat);

            }

            SizeF size = g.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);
            RectangleF layoutRect = new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, size.Width, size.Height);

            List<Region[]> regions = new List<Region[]>();

            for(int i = 0; i < characterRanges.Count; i++) {
                regions.Add(new Region[characterRanges[i].Length]);
                regions[i] = e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(
                measureString,
                stringFont,
                layoutRect,
                stringFormats[i]);
            }

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < numChars; i++ )
            {
                int block = (int) Math.Floor((double) i / 32);
                Region region = regions[block][i - (32 * block)] as Region;
                RectangleF rect = region.GetBounds(g);
                rect.Offset( i * 10, 0);
                g.DrawString( measureString.Substring(i,1), stringFont, Brushes.Black, rect, stringFormats[block]);
                // g.DrawRectangle( Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round( rect ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm adaptating this code: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7375/Using-MeasureCharacterRanges-to-Draw-Text (This don't work with strings that have more then 32 chars)

Comment: What should happen when you hit a line break?  Start back at left zero?

Comment: When the line breaks, the next line have to start in the same X position that the first line started. And if I wanted to place a little space after the first line, `StringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;` should solve this, but StringAlignment is not working at all.

Comment: The second string is not centered. When a `\n` is printed, the string goes to a new line and this breaks the measurement. You need to split the original string using `\n` as separator, then use `foreach` to print each string, adding an `Y` Offset to your `layoutRect`. The Y Offset could be calculated using the `Font.Height` + an interline value, if needed. Note that this method does not keep track of the painting surface size, it just adds a default spacing between chars. It will paint outside the canvas bounds when the string doesn't fit.